# Column in field list is ambiguous error

Tags: sql, join

i've been recently working in mysql and in one of the requests i wrote :

```
SELECT SIGLE_EEP, ID_SOUS_MODULE, LIBELLE 
FROM mef_edi.eep a, mef_edi.envoi e, mef_edi.sous_module s 
WHERE a.ID_EEP =  e.ID_EEP 
AND a.ID_SOUS_MODULE = s.ID_SOUS_MODULE;
```

and they told me :

> Column `ID_SOUS_MODULE` in field list is ambiguous

What should i do ?

Comment: Please format you code (Ctrl+K)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I still use "old-style JOINs", I think the JOIN syntax is a pain and I don't see its use discouraged by most people.

Answer (score 2):

More than one table has a column named `ID_SOUS_MODULE`.

So you need to name the table every time you mention the column to specify which table you mean.

Change

```
SELECT ID_SOUS_MODULE
```

for instance to

```
SELECT a.ID_SOUS_MODULE
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above, you may have duplicate column names across your 3 tables, assigning the table id (a, e, s) as noted above will avoid that issue in the select. In addition to what @juergen said you may want to get rid of that cartesian join by using an inner or left join (inner seems to be what your going for). The way you are joining your table you are joining every possible combination of rows together than filtering. using a proper join will get you better performance in the long run as your table line counts grow. Here is an example of a non cartesian join:

```
SELECT SIGLE_EEP, ID_SOUS_MODULE, LIBELLE 
FROM mef_edi.eep a
INNER JOIN mef_edi.envoi e ON (a.ID_EEP =  e.ID_EEP) 
INNER JOIN mef_edi.sous_module s ON (a.ID_SOUS_MODULE = s.ID_SOUS_MODULE)
```